# Issue with group by and order by clause with inner join

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

I have two tables namely locations and pilots. I have been trying to fetch data based on location_id i.e selecting pilots who are flying in a particular location_id order by date(date of schedule).

I am using group by as i need only distinct pilots to be displayed.

```
select  B.*, 
    A.rather_to_be_flying_now,
    A.here_now,
    A.flying,
    A.when,
    A.my_favorite,
    A.start,
    A.end,
    A.Locationid
from locations A 
inner join pilots B 
    on A.Pilotid=B.pilot_id 
where A.VenueID='$venueid' 
    and (A.flying='1' or A.here_now='1') 
group by A.Pilotid 
ORDER BY A.start
```

The query works good if i wont include a group by clause. It returns the following result

**with out group by clause**
[image]

**with group by clause**
[image]

But the above table shows wrong order, as the output must return start time as **2013-01-24 02:00:00** for pilotid 1 (Chronological order).

Comment: Try changing `A.start` to `MIN(A.start)`

Comment: I got another issue , if i use MIN(A.start) the remaining column values are altered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `MIN()`

```
select  B.*, 
    A.rather_to_be_flying_now,
    A.here_now,
    A.flying,
    A.when,
    A.my_favorite,
    MIN(A.start) as start,
    A.end,
    A.Locationid
from locations A 
inner join pilots B 
    on A.Pilotid=B.pilot_id 
where A.VenueID='$venueid' 
    and (A.flying='1' or A.here_now='1') 
group by A.Pilotid 
ORDER BY A.start
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
SELECT
  B.*,
  A.rather_to_be_flying_now,
  A.here_now,
  A.flying,
  A.when,
  A.my_favorite,
  A.start,
  A.end,
  A.Locationid
FROM locations A 
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT pilotid, MIN(start) MinStart
   FROM locations
   GROUP BY pilotid
) a2  ON A.pilotId = a2.pilotId
     AND a.start   = a2.minStart 
INNER JOIN pilots B on A.Pilotid = B.pilot_id 
WHERE A.VenueID = '$venueid' 
  AND (A.flying='1' OR A.here_now='1');
ORDER BY A.start ;
```

This will give you only those pilots with the minimum start date.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query -

```
SELECT
  p.pilit_id, l.location_id, l.start
FROM pilots p
  JOIN (SELECT l1.*
        FROM locations l1
        JOIN (SELECT location_id, MIN(start) start
              FROM locations
              GROUP BY locations) l2
        ON l1.id = l2.id AND l1.start = l2.start
        ) l
    ON l.pilot_id = p.pilot_id
GROUP BY p.pilot_id
```

Add your WHERE condition.